# SQL Multiple columns same join column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 3 columns in my table Travel (and of course some more):

AirportFrom,
AirportTo,
AirportFound.

The columns above display ID's from airports. In the table Airports are 2 columns AirportID and AirportName. 
Instead of displaying the ID's from the airports I want to display the AirportNames.

But when I use:

```
SELECT id
     , AirportFrom
     , Airports.Airportname
     , AirportTo
     , Airports.Airportname
     , AirportFound
     , Airports.Airportname 
  FROM Travel 
  LEFT 
  JOIN Airports 
    ON AirportTo = Airports.AirportID
-- LEFT JOIN Airports ON AirportFrom = Airports.AirportID
-- LEFT JOIN Airports ON AirportFound = Airports.AirportID
```

It only displays the airport name of the first join in every column. I want to show the airport name for each of the 3 joins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide multiple aliases for joined table each time you left join, and join them as you have multiple tables:

```
SELECT 
    Travel.id, 
    airport_to.Airportname as to_name, 
    airport_from.Airportname as from_name, 
    airport_found.Airportname as found_name, 
FROM Travel 
LEFT JOIN Airports airport_to ON Travel.AirportTo = airport_to.AirportID
LEFT JOIN Airports airport_from ON Travel.AirportFrom = airport_from.AirportID
LEFT JOIN Airports airport_found ON Travel.AirportFound = airport_found.AirportID
```

EDIT: Replace reserved words in table aliases. Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: up vote. better readability and understandability vis-a-vis other answer

Comment: watch out for reserved words

Answer (score 1):

Your query needs table aliases (for multiple joins to the same table).  Then, be sure to use qualified columns names for all columns in a query.  This helps you write correct queries and it helps you and other people understand what is going on.  So:

```
SELECT t.id, t.AirportFrom, apt.Airportname,
       t.AirportTo, apf.Airportname,
       t.AirportFound, apfo.Airportname 
FROM Travel t LEFT JOIN
     Airports apt
     ON t.AirportTo = apt.AirportID LEFT JOIN
     Airports apf
     ON t.AirportFrom = apf.AirportID LEFT JOIN
     Airports apfo
     ON t.AirportFound = apfo.AirportID;
```